# Create Record using java script in crm 2011

Tags: javascript, json, dynamics-crm-2011, crm

I am using CRM2011 on-Premises I create a custom entity record on account form using json.
It working fine for me but for other user it shows "Access Denied"
note( user has same role like me)

If anyone has an idea please share with me.

Comment: Is the access denied the standard CRM permissions error or a JavaScript / webserver access denied? The code would help as @guido said

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes this happens because the enviroment is https and the users are using http.

Crm may work fine but javascripts usually don't work in this way.

Hope this can help you.